# Does net-snmp for CentOS support SNMP v2 and v1?

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, snmp, net-snmp

CentOS 5.9 | net-snmp-5.3.2.2

I'm running netsnmp on a CentOS 5.9 box and it's unclear to me from the config on whether or not it support SNMP v2 and v1.

I've always used SNMP v3 and /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf is very barebones:

```
syslocation  "in the box"
syscontact  bob@foo.com
rouser  fooadmin priv
```

Since there aren't any other users or communities specified, is it reasonable to assume that SNMP v2 and v1 won't work out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

The snmpd.conf file should contain a few other parameters by default, among them is the community "public" which has access to the system info MIB (OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.1 ). This should work for any version of SNMP. You can enable broader access to other MIBs, restrict by IP etc with very little effort.

Comment: Thanks.  So am I correct in assuming that if the community parameter isn't specified, snmp v1 and v2 won't work?

Comment: That's correct, with no community string any v1 or v2 request should fail